# Ajax giving Acess Denied error

Tags: ajax, security, web

I am trying to AJAX a request to 192.158.110.129:5000 (Flask Webserver), while the whole website is served by 192.168.110.129:8080(Apache). I get Access denied error in all browsers . How can I resolve this ? 
I need to understand whats happening , so that I can fix it . 
document.domain="192.168.110.129" in Firefox .
I think this is some cross site script injection security measure but can anyone clarify ?

There isn't much code I can show for this as I am using API's. It is something like this.
I have a HTML with textarea that is loaded with CKEDITOR script . I access this through APACHE . Now for spell checking I modified their plugin and am sending a request to a flash web server .

```
request = "192.158.110.129:5000?data=data"
var data=CKEDITOR.ajax.load(request);
```

This doesn't get through .

So file serving through Apache and Ajaxing to a flash server for Python action . 
**Someone suggested that 'Proxy' or JSONP would be good solutions . Any where I can read up on that** ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with XSS; this is CSRF related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XHR requests are restricted by a [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) that allows only requests within the same origin due to security reasons. So 192.168.110.129 is only allowed to send XHR requests to 192.168.110.129 but not 192.158.110.129.

Changing `document.domain` doesn’t help here. Besides that you are only allowed to use a proper (super-) domain like `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com` could agree on `example.com`, this is only for DOM access and not XHR requests.

An extension to XHR is the [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) that allows cross-origin requests under specific conditions. One condition is that the receiving site authorizes requests from the scripts site. This is done with the [*Access-Control-Allow-Origin* response header field](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-hea). It can either contain a list of allowed origins or `*` as a wildcard.

So try to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on your 192.158.110.129 machine.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, most browsers disallow XSS. You have two options.

1. Whatever service you have on 192.**158**.110.129, move it onto 192.**168**.110.129 so there is no more XSS
2. Create a server side .php (or similar) proxy script on 192.**158**.110.129. This server side script does not have XSS limitations and can retrieve resources from 192.**168**.110.129, and then be dynamically accessed by AJAX from 192.**158**.110.129.

If you post some code, I will be much obliged to provide example corrections.